# Get +1 Element in JSON Path

Tags: arrays, json, xpath, jsonpath

I'm trying to work within library constraints and need to define a JSON Path that gets the *next* object of a list, based on a capturing value's index.

Take the following example:

```
{[ 
    x, 
    info of x, 
    y, 
    info of y
]}
```

I want a JSON path that gets info of X, regardless of x's position, with the knowledge that info of x will always be the next item after x. So as to say, there can be another array

```
{[ 
    y,
    y info,
    x,
    x info,
    z,
    z info
]}
```

where I still want to get info of x, but the index of x has changed.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have any control over the JSON payload, but typically you'd want to use an object for this kind of data.  `{"x": <x info>}` would be a more appropriate representation.  This would be easy to develop a JSON Path for, but with the payload in this state, you can't do it with JSON Path.

Answer (score 0):

I think indexOf is what you want.

```
const json = ['y', 'y info', 'x', 'x info', 'z', 'z info'];
const xinfo = json[json.indexOf('x')+1];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use a JSON Path. Is there any such fn for JSONPaths (I couldn't find any in my search)?

Comment: There's not a way to do this with JSON Path.  Can you elaborate why you need a JSON Path solution?

Comment: I see, ok thanks. I'm working within a library's set of fns.